# .NET.. runtime error "assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I copied a .NET project over from one computer to another.   When I compile it, it compiles ok, but when it loads in the browser, i get the following error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit (1410)' or one of its   dependencies.    The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit (1410)' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm not really familar w/ .NET so I'm unsure what other steps I need to take in order to get this to compile and run successfully.

I checked my REFERENCES .. and I can see the (AjaxControlToolKit.dll)..  So I'm wondering what else I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to see what dependencies you are missing and where it is trying to find them.

Comment: Hmm I tried opening the fusion log viewer, but nothing shows up when I compile the app  in visual studio

Comment: I updated the link to point to the newer documentation. You have to set the logging settings. By default it does not log anything. You want to set it to LogBindFailuresToDisk

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I don't have administrator privleges on the machine :( It says I have to run it as an administrator

Comment: You can try Dependency Walker, but you might need admin privileges there also. Otherwise, you could use some sort of reflection tool to read the manifest dependencies?

Comment: Ok I finally was able to get admin rights to my machine, specifically just to try and debug this issue! :)  I ran the fusion log viewer 'fuslogvw', i get results but when I view each result I get "The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.
"  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hrmmm, that is very odd to me. Well, you can try using a decompiler (JustDecompile is free) and decompiling the AjaxControlToolkit to see what References are listed. Any non-system ones probably require a dll to be present in the bin or GAC

Comment: Ok I'll try that.  One more clue as to the possible issue.  I copied this project from ONE machine to another machine. Do I possibly need to copy other files other than the project files?

Comment: You need everything that went into the bin. However you cannot rule out something being pulled in from the gac. I am still surprised there isn't anything in fusion